# How do I handle the grounded neutral for a simple switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, code-compliance

I trying to move a switch, which is currently in a 2-gang box.  The 2-gang box will need to stay in place (and covered with a plate) as it is also the junction of some other stuff (currently power comes into the box, and feeds the switched light, and 2 branches of outlets).  With new codes, I need to have a grounded neutral in the relocated switch.  My plan is to do the following:

[image: Relocated switch]

Note, I have excluded all the other stuff that is in the existing 2-gang box.  My question is- what do I do with the neutral in the 1-gang switch box?  My existing toggle switches do not have a connection for a neutral (they are not "smart" switches).  Do I just cap the neutral line in the single-gang box?  Are there new toggle switches that accept a neutral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply cap it with a twist-on wire connector, or other approved method.

Comment: Thanks Tester.  That is what I figured, but wanted to make sure I am all ready for inspection.